# Expression to check agent form Apache log and extract IP if apache status code 200

Tags: regex

I need get create a regex rule for extract second Ip on my apache log, for security questions.

But i don't know how to filter agent

I need extract second IP on log (**121.54.54.226**) when agent condition = **Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1**

```
176.XX.XX.233 121.54.54.226 - - [22/Aug/2016:10:44:12 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3714 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1"
```

For get IP on wordpress failed login work for me: (extract 121.54.54.226)

```
\s(\S+).*] "POST \/wp-login\.php.*" 200
```

But when try filter for agent fails

```
\s(\S+).*] "POST \/wp-login\.php.*" 200 \d+ \"\-\" \""Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/40.1"\"
```

No matches.

Comment: Please try to rephrase. Which IP addresses are you looking for; what works; what doesn't?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape all regex meta characters like this:

```
/\s(\S+).* "POST \/wp-login\.php.*" 200 \d+ "-" "Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0\) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/40.1"/
```

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/FBTiFgL7HH)

Comment: I'm sorry for my question. I explained wrong. I do not need to capture the agent, but this filter. That is, if the agent meets the condition of being in the log, then remove the IP. I correct my post now.

Comment: I think perl. It's for rules with CSF Firewall. http://rubular.com/r/tLMEvHDQAq If on this code change any string on agent, match result. I like only if "Agent it's same at model"

Comment: Try this regex [`/\s(\S+).* "POST \/wp-login\.php.*" 200 \d+ "-" "Mozilla\/5\.0[^"]*"/`](http://rubular.com/r/j8YOaLq6Xc)

Comment: Well. now it work for exacilly agent... (as I wanted) \s(\S+).*] "POST \/wp-login\.php.*" 200 \d+ "-" "Mozilla\/5\.0 \(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0\) Gecko\/20100101 Firefox\/40.1" A lot of thanks http://rubular.com/r/0BiUpN41sn